# What causes packet loss when using full bandwidth from ISP?

Tags: routing, latency, isp, packet-loss, adsl

We have a small, local ISP that is having some networking issues and I'm trying to understand the cause to better communicate with their network guys. I work with a number of companies with different network/router configurations using their service (dsl).

We have a range of issues but the most repeatable one is that packets are dropped when using a large amount of bandwidth. For example, when I run a speed test and I have a couple pings running at the same time, I see packet loss go to 50 percent and latency go to 10 times what it was. This happens regardless of the customer's configuration.

I've seen the same thing happen when someone is, for example, uploading an album to facebook. All other wan traffic becomes unstable, with high latency and lots of dropped packets. Even when we are not using much bandwidth, however, we still see intermittent packet loss and often unexpectadly high latency's for customers on their network.

- For a novice network admin trying to understand the issue, is the
  most likely culprit here a problem with the DSL equipment or an
  insufficient router to handle their traffic?
- How can I test to better understand what is going on?
- What would be the best way to
  demonstrate the problem to them (and that it is happening for all
  their customers), so as to provide their networking guy with the
  necessary info to resolve the problem?

Comment: Sounds more like you're oversubscribed somewhere. Please refer to http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/collateral/data-center-virtualization/storage-networking-solution/net_implementation_white_paper0900aecd800f592f.html for some helpful information.

Comment: See Also: Queueing (fifo, wred, etc.), and Queue Depth

Comment: It would help us to know what equipment is being used to suggest commands and further troubleshooting.

Comment: Try pinging the far end of your link, i.e the next hop after your local router, and see if you get similar results.

Comment: Note that with DSL, 80ms ping time are about as good as it gets and up to 250ms is not uncommon with DSL. Since it is DSL, you provider likely knows that it's not going to be that great. They aren't going to replace their infrastructure even if you could prove it unless they were planning these upgrades already.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks to the many people who answered this question, I started to reconfigure Queuing on my router. A speed test will work at 6.5 Mbps download and 0.65 Mbps upload, but when either watching a movie or uploading to Google Drive, the error rate would exceed 20% and the latency would be over 200 mSec. With Queuing set for 5.5 / 0.50 Mbps, things seem to be working much better. Thanks again for the advice. My ISP has tried to work on this, and even sent the local telco CLEC out to do testing, but nobody ever suggested that the problem was due to their buffers being too large.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of possibilities here, not limited to, but including:

1. The CPE's CPU is maxing out. (CPE=Customer Premesis Device)

   Check the specifications for the router you are using to make sure it can support the level of traffic you're trying to push. Try and graph the CPE's CPU if you are unsure.
2. Bufferbloat in your ISP

   If your ISP has configured traffic shaping for DSL tails (to avoid tail dropping packets) - they may have configured their buffer size too large. A good way to tell is by maxing out your connection in the downstream (download) direction. If your latency goes up by 200ms or more, this is probably a problem with your ISP's shaping configuration for DSL tails, and you should complain. They should reduce their buffer depth.

   I'd suggest >50ms of buffer is harmful.
3. The upstream of your xDSL is being maxed out.

   Remember on most DSL technologies, bandwidth is asymmetric. Thus it takes a much smaller amount of traffic to congest the upstream (upload) on most DSL technologies than the downstream. 
   Make sure you aren't congesting upstream.
4. Remember tools that graph links are usually averaging samples.

   Tools like rrdtool (and cacti and NMIS and...) are usually showing you a 5-minute sample average of your links. This makes them poor for identifying situations where a user congests a link for 10 seconds or so. That'll just appear as a small bump on a 5-minute-sampled graph. Look for tools which can give you a 'high water mark' of the link as well as a rolling average.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware, ICMP is bottom-of-the-barrel traffic. During high utilization, you should expect ICMP to drop. It is set up to be dropped first in almost every single scenario, to make way for real data.

So how do you test?

[TCPing](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php) is one way. This sends TCP SYN packets and times how long it takes to get an ACK back. You do need to know an open port on the other side to TCPing, but this gives you a good view of how actual TCP traffic is performing.

TCPing should tell you end-to-end your performance, but you already know there's some kind of trouble. How do you isolate it?

[WinMTR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winmtr/files/Latest/) to the rescue! This basically runs a traceroute constantly, and collects the latency data on each hop. When you see the latency suddenly increase, you've probably got your culprit... especially if it's persistent.

These are 2 tools I use regularly to help isolate where issues exist.

If you isolate the issue to a device you have SNMP access to, but not CLI/GUI access to, you can use [SNMPWalk and SNMPGet](http://www.snmpsoft.com/freetools/) to dig deeper. I recommend this as a last-ditch effort, since the "S" in "SNMP" stands for something it isn't to mere mortals: Simple. But oh, the information you can eventually coax out of it.

Answer (score 0):

congestion at the network nodes

Comment: Please consider adding more details to your answer.